# Is there list of apprenticeship types for FindMyPast record set called Britain, Country Apprentices 1710-1808?

Tags: england, 18th-century, scotland, wales, apprenticeship-records

A new set of records has come online at FindMyPast called **[Britain, Country Apprentices 1710-1808](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/search-world-Records/britain-country-apprentices-1710-1808)**:

> What was your family trade? Discover your ancestor in the registers
>   from the Board of Stamps. The registers recorded the tax paid for each
>   indenture for an apprentice. The average apprenticeship was seven
>   years. That is seven years of family history you can reveal through
>   these records, as well as your ancestor’s parent’s name, his/her
>   master and the profession they chose. The registers record
>   apprenticeships from the whole of Great Britain.

I suspect that a number of my ancestors are awaiting my discovery in them.

I maintain a list of occupations uncovered for my ancestors and which ancestors were engaged in each (and when) and I plan to go through them systematically.

Is there a definitive list of occupations for which apprenticeship records can be found in the aforementioned set of records?

Comment: Just so you know, these records (with original images, which are not on FindMyPast) have been available on Ancestry.co.uk for several years http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=1851

Comment: Also, if you cannot access Ancestry.co.uk, you can access the images for free on the National Archives website (you have to browse through the relevant piece): http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/browse/r/r/C9339?uri=C9339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General information about apprenticeships can be found on the National Archives website: [Looking for records of an apprentice or master](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/records/looking-for-person/apprentice.htm).

This index on FindMyPast was derived from the Stamp Duty registers, held by the National Archives in series IR 1. The images from which the index was derived can be viewed for free on the National Archives website, by browsing the [Discovery catalogue](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/browse/r/r/C9339?uri=C9339) to the relevant year and piece. Note that the same records have been indexed on [Ancestry.co.uk](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=1851) since 2011, and Ancestry.co.uk includes both an index and images.

I doubt there is a *definitive* list of occupations.

In a research paper titled [Apprenticeship and Occupations in Southern England, 1710-1760](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/webteam/gateway/file.php?name=paper24.pdf&site=11), using the Stamp Duty registers (IR 1) as their source, the author analyzes the number of each occupation for three counties (Surrey, Sussex, and Wiltshire). The data can be viewed on [pages 16-17](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/webteam/gateway/file.php?name=paper24.pdf&site=11). The list from this paper includes all occupations from these three counties that occurred in these records 5 or more times. I have put the list in alphabetical order:

> Apothecary
>   Attorney
>   Basketmaker
>   Baker
>   Barber
>   Blacksmith
>   Bodicemaker
>   Brazier
>   Bricklayer
>   Broadweaver
>   Butcher
>   Cabinet-maker
>   Carpenter
>   Chandler
>   Clockmaker
>   Clothier
>   Clothworker
>   Collarmaker
>   Cooper
>   Cordwainer
>   Currier
>   Cutler
>   Draper
>   Druggett-maker
>   Dyer
>   Farrier
>   Fellmonger
>   Feltmaker
>   Flaxdresser
>   Gardener
>   Glazier
>   Glazier-plumber
>   Glover
>   Grocer
>   Gunsmith
>   Hatter
>   House-carpenter
>   Housewife
>   Innholder
>   Ironmonger
>   Joiner
>   Kersey-weaver
>   Knacker
>   Linen weaver
>   Linen-draper
>   Maltster
>   Mantua-maker
>   Mason
>   Mercer
>   Merchant-tailor
>   Miller
>   Milliner
>   Millwright
>   Needlemaker
>   Painter
>   Parchment maker
>   Pattenmaker
>   Periwig-maker
>   Pipemaker
>   Plumber
>   Ropemaker
>   Saddler
>   Sailor
>   Sawyer
>   Seamstress
>   Sergemaker
>   Shearmaker
>   Shipwright
>   Shoemaker
>   Shopkeeper
>   Soap-maker
>   Spinster
>   Staymaker
>   Stone mason
>   Surgeon
>   Tailor
>   Tallow chandler
>   Tanner
>   Turner
>   Upholsterer
>   Victualler
>   Watchmaker
>   Waterman
>   Weaver
>   Wheelwright
>   Woolcomber
>   Woollen draper
>   Woolstapler
>   Writing master

Also, on the [Guildhall Library website](http://www.history.ac.uk/gh/livdet.html) is one list of companies in London, and includes most of the major occupations that would be apprenticed:

> Apothecaries, Armourers and Brasiers
>
> Bakers, Barbers (ca. 1540-1745 Barber Surgeons), Basketmakers,
>   Blacksmiths, Bowyers, Brewers, Broderers, Butchers
>
> Carmen, Carpenters, Clockmakers, Coach and Coach Harness Makers,
>   Combmakers, Cooks, Coopers, Cordwainers, Curriers, Cutlers
>
> Distillers, Dyers
>
> Fanmakers, Farriers, Fellowship Porters, Feltmakers, Fishmongers,
>   Fletchers, Founders, Framework Knitters, Fruiterers
>
> Gardeners, Girdlers, Glass Sellers, Glaziers, Glovers, Gold and Silver
>   Wyre Drawers, Grocers, Gunmakers
>
> Haberdashers, Horners
>
> Innholders, Ironmongers
>
> Joiners and Ceilers
>
> Longbowstringmakers, Loriners
>
> Masons, Merchant Taylors#, Musicians
>
> Needlemakers
>
> Painter Stainers, Parish Clerks, Pattenmakers, Paviors, Pewterers,
>   Pinmakers, Plaisterers, Playing Card Makers, Plumbers, Poulters
>
> Saddlers (some only, see paragraph 3), Scriveners, Shipwrights,
>   Skinners, Spectacemakers
>
> Tacklehouse and Ticket Porters, Tallow Chandlers, Tin Plate Workers,
>   Tobacco Pipe Makers, Turners, Tylers and Bricklayers
>
> Upholders
>
> Vintners
>
> Watermen and Lightermen, Wax Chandlers, Weavers

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly the sort of list(s) that I was looking for.  I have a World Ancestry subscription along with my UK FindMyPast but had not connected that these were the same record set.  Still it will do me no harm to go through them in a new way, and more systematically.

Answer (score 2):

The Statute of Apprentices of 1563 made it illegal for anyone to enter specified trades without having served an apprenticeship. I use the word "specified" here, as one of the reasons for the eventual decline of the apprenticeship system under the 1563 rules was the emergence of trades outside the scope of the 1563 Act - which implies there was a specific scope.

See the [FamilySearch Wiki on apprenticeships](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Apprenticeship_in_England), itself taken from an Anthony Camp article.

The 1563 Act is apparently also known as the Statute of Artificers and the closest I have been able to find to a paraphrase of it, is an article on [Elizabethan apprenticeships](http://www.elizabethan.org/compendium/80.html), which does have a list of trades - though how accurate and comprehensive it might be, I can't tell without the text of the original.

There are several caveats:

- Apprenticeships arranged by the Parish under the Poor Law did not pay duty, so will not appear in those IR1 registers on Ancestry, FindMyPast or the TNA downloads;
- Apprenticeships of son to father (etc.) will similarly not appear as the father is unlikely to pay himself to take on his son as an apprentice! Hence no duty was payable;
- The prohibition is against entering a *trade* without serving an apprenticeship - or, to try to be clearer, you can't *trade* as an X without serving an apprenticeship. If you're not in business for yourself, the prohibition does not apply. The example I always quote is from Dundee (in Scotland so not under the same Act), where it took 7 years to serve an apprenticeship as a weaver but only about 6 or 7 weeks to be trained to work a hand-loom. The 6 or 7 week weaver could only ever work for someone else and be paid for their labour, never for the product itself.

Comment: The relevant sections of the Statute of Artificers begin at section 31, full text here: https://books.google.com/books?id=BkZLAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PA8&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I hope I'm right in saying that the apprenticeship requirement only applies if you're in business as an X. It's certainly true in that case for Dundee - just hope the different legal system isn't muddying the waters. If I think of textile towns in England then there are lots of weavers' cottages built for doing home-based work - I can't believe each of those cottages contained a weaver who'd served a 7y apprenticeship. How could such industries expand so quickly?

Comment: From what I've read people were rarely prosecuted for breaking this law. My understanding is that the law only technically appied not if someone called themselves a weaver, but if they acted in the capacity of a master (employing other apprentices or employees). This is an interesting take on the question so thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Prosecution may depend on where you were. 3G-GF's father-in-law from his 2nd marriage was "prosecuted" by the Merchants' Guild of Dundee in 1808 - presumably for trading as a Merchant. He was a Master of the Hammerman's Guild (as a jeweller) but, so far as I can see, only a Merchant could buy in work from others and sell it on. (Buying in work and commissioning others to do work are not the same thing. Ownership of the goods does not change in the 2nd case). However, at this stage, the whole Guild process was starting to break down in Dundee and it appears nothing came of the case.