# Apprenticeship records or trade information for 1830s Sheffield, Yorkshire?

Tags: 19th-century, england, occupation, yorkshire, apprenticeship-records

This is the same family as in the related question [Finding residence information for Toronto in the 1840s?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/9261/1006)

I have two references to George Hindley in Sheffield, Yorkshire -- both identify him as a tailor.  I'm looking for apprentice records or trade records that might provide further clues to George's origin.

The clues I have in Yorkshire:

- [1841 Census](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MQ5H-F3N) HO107/1338/23 on Bailey street in Sheffield (extract from FamilySearch) -- [transcription at findmypast](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/record?id=gbc%2F1841%2F0010235576) and [image at findmypast](http://search.findmypast.co.uk/record?id=GBC/1841/1338/0188&parentid=GBC/1841/0010235538):

> - Joseph Butler       M   40-44   Yorkshire
> - Mary Butler         F   42-46   Yorkshire
> - Ann Drake       F   22-26   Yorkshire
> - John Drake      M   3   Yorkshire
> - George Hindley      M   20-24

George's entry is marked N (Not born in this County).

- marriage announced in the Sheffield Independent August 14, 1841 Page 5:

> On Sunday last, at Upper Chapel, by the Rev. B. T. Stannus, Mr. George Hindley, tailor, to Miss Hannah Drake.

Massachusetts records, which pointed toward Sheffield, also gave their parents' names:

- The marriage record in Massachusetts from George's second marriage in Pittsfield, Massachusetts (1857) and his Massachusetts death registration (1885) in North Adams say that his father's name was **Samuel** but no mother's name is given.
- Hannah's death registration from Williamstown, Massachusetts in 1856 says that her father's name was **Jonathan Drake**.

George and Hannah's oldest children were born in Canada (1844) and New York State (1845-6?); all the rest were born in Massachusetts. My best guess for this couples' migration path, based on the records in hand and the reported birthplaces of all the children, is from Sheffield to Toronto, Canada, to Albany New York (via the NY canals or railroads), to Berkshire County, Massachusetts. The date range for emigration is between August 1841 when the couple got married in Sheffield, and Samuel's birth in Toronto (5 Feb 1844 according to Samuel's Naturalization records).

George's son Samuel is a shoemaker. While looking for possible records for Samuel Hindley (candidates for George's father), I found a Samuel Hindley, shoemaker, in nearby East Retford, Notts. -- according to GENUKI nearby places, 22.3 miles (35.9 Km) to the E of Sheffield.

This entry for a George Drake Hindley, a British subject born in the USA, enumarated in Brightside Bierlow, Yorkshire West Riding in the 1871 Census ([indexed at FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VBCT-HFR)) may be George Hindley's son, born 1855 in Williamstown, Berkshire County, Massachusetts, and is under investigation.

Trying to find information on extended family plus friends, associates, and neighbors in Massachusetts has been problematic -- any possible business or occupational-related records for Yorkshire West Riding and the surrounding area would be useful, including general papers on industry in the area for context.

Comment: http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/apprentices-and-masters/ may or may not be useful as a reminder that "Official records of apprentices were kept in England and Wales between 1710 and 1811, when stamp duty was payable on indentures of apprenticeship."  @HarryVervet pointed me to it in http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/9162

Comment: Thanks --  I re-visited that guide shortly after writing the question. Checking trade directories next.  Any ideas on how to re-tool the question are welcome.